# "Functionoids"?

Tags: c++, boost

I've read the description of "functionoids" [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#functionoids). They look like a poor-man's version of Boost::function and Boost::bind. Am I missing something? Is there a good reason to use them if you're already using Boost?

Comment: I think there's one place where one might be tempted to use functionoids with a virtual, overridable calling method... that would be for an API where using boost or std::function might not be possible, or for APIs that need to be bound to a scripting language like Lua. The functionoid approach, while being less flexible, is easier to use across APIs and module boundaries and across different compilers than something as sophisticated as boost::function or std::function, even though it is not nearly as flexible or convenient (at least it's a step up from a function pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Alternatively see the FQA answer [here.](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html#fqa-33.10)

Answer (score 3):

My vote goes to tr1::function.

*Functors* or *functionoids* represent the base from which `tr1/boost::function` has evolved. The limit with common-interface functors is that they break the OO-paradigm since they represent different types and can only passed to template functions (unless you provide a base class from which they derive from).

Indeed by means of the *[type erasure technique](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure2.html)* `tr1::function` overcomes this limit: They are best used to implement dynamic *strategy classes*.